# AFNetworking - Stream 0x96c93c0 is sending an event before being opened

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, afnetworking

I am trying to send some data to `AFNetworking` to my server but when I want to send the data the following error appear in the console log and the server never received the data.

Does anyone know why I am reciving this error?

```
2013-06-06 17:02:16.246 iGym[15255:c07] Stream 0xa267930 is sending an event before being opened
2013-06-06 17:02:17.277 iGym[15255:c07] Inside the success block (null)
```

The code

```
-(void) shareExercise {


    Exercise* myExercise = [self getCurrentExercise];

    if (![myExercise.author isEqualToString:@"me"] )
    {
        // TODO: Error you cannnot share an exercise that is not yours
    }


    User* myUser = [self getCurrentUser];

    if (myUser.nickname == nil) {
        // You need a
    }

    NSData *exercisePictureThumb = [[NSData alloc] init];
    NSData *exerciseDesPic1 = [[NSData alloc] init];
    NSData *exercisePic = [[NSData alloc] init];
    // Sort the pictures out
    if(myExercise.exercisePictureThumb){
        UIImage* image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:myExercise.exercisePictureThumb];
        exercisePictureThumb = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1);
    }
    if(myExercise.exerciseDesPic1){
        UIImage* image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:myExercise.exerciseDesPic1];
        exerciseDesPic1 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image2);
    }
    if(myExercise.exercisePic){
        UIImage* image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:myExercise.exercisePic];
        exercisePic = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image3);
    }

    NSDictionary *params = @{@"userID":(myUser.idUserExternal ? myUser.idUserExternal : @"0"),
                             @"interact":@{
                                     @"action":@"add",
                                     @"actionTarget":@"exercise"},
                             @"share":@{@"exercise":@{ 
                                                @"exerciseType":(myExercise.exerciseType ? @"1" : @"0"),
                                                         @"exerciseName":(myExercise.exerciseName ? myExercise.exerciseName  : @"0"),
                                                         @"exerciseAuthorID":(myUser.nickname ? myUser.nickname : @"0"),
                                                         @"exerciseDescription":(myExercise.exerciseDescription ? myExercise.exerciseDescription : @"0"),
                                                         @"exerciseYoutube":(myExercise.exerciseYoutube ? myExercise.exerciseYoutube : @"0"),
                                                         @"exerciseID":(myExercise.exerciseWebID ? myExercise.exerciseWebID : @"0"),
                                                         @"exercisePicture":(myExercise.exercisePic ? myExercise.exercisePic : @"0"),
                                                         @"exerciseDescriptionPic1":(myExercise.exerciseDesPic1 ? myExercise.exerciseDesPic1 : @"0"),
                                                         @"exercisePictureThumb":(myExercise.exercisePictureThumb ? myExercise.exercisePictureThumb : @"0")

                                                      }
                                        }
                             };
    NSLog(@"%@",params);

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://192.168.1.64/"];
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc]initWithBaseURL:url];


    NSURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"igym/bootstrap.php" parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)
                             {
                                 /*
                                 if(myExercise.exercisePictureThumb){
                                     [formData appendPartWithFileData:exercisePictureThumb name:@"asd" fileName:myExercise.exercisePictureThumb mimeType:@"image/png"];
                                 }
                                 if(myExercise.exerciseDesPic1){
                                     [formData appendPartWithFileData:exerciseDesPic1 name:@"asd" fileName:myExercise.exerciseDesPic1 mimeType:@"image/png"];
                                 }
                                 if(myExercise.exercisePic){
                                     [formData appendPartWithFileData:exercisePic name:@"asd" fileName:myExercise.exercisePic mimeType:@"image/png"];
                                 }
                                 */

                             }];



    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                                                        success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON){
                                                                                            NSLog(@"Inside the success block %@",JSON);
                                                                                        }
                                                                                        failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON){

                                                                                            NSLog(@"json text is: %@", JSON);
                                                                                            NSLog(@"Request failed with error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
                                                                                        }];
    [operation start];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**  Looks like [this accepted pull request](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/pull/1044) should resolve your issue.  Update AFNetworking, and complete your constructor block.

---

1. You need to put some code in your constructor block; it appears yours is commented out.
2. There is an [open issue related to this](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/948) on the AFNetworking GitHub site (it's been around for about a month).  A few patches have been applied but it doesn't look 100% resolved.  You may want to make sure you are using the latest build of AFNetworking.